# Is there a way to set multiple different destinations for responsive-images in grunt.js?

Tags: image, responsive-design, gruntjs

Here is the code that I have. I want to set a different destination for each different sized file, just to keep my file tree a little bit more organized. Obviously, what I have doesn't work, do I need to first put them all in the same folder, then somehow move them into their proper files? If that is the case, could you walk me through how to go about doing that?

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-responsive-images');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
    grunt.initConfig({
        uglify: {
            js: {
                src: 'assets/js/*.js',
                dest: 'assets/min-files/main.min.js'
            },
        },
        cssmin: {
            dev: {
                options: {
                    report: 'min'
                },
                src: 'assets/css/*.css',
                dest: 'assets/min-files/main.min.css'
            }
        },
        responsive_images: {
            dev: {
                options: {},
                sizes: [{
                    name: 'small',
                    width:320,
                    height: 240,
                    suffix:'jpg',
                    dest: 'assets/images/main-page-bg/small'
                },{
                    name: 'medium',
                    width: 640,
                    quality: 80,
                    suffix:'jpg',
                    dest: 'assets/images/main-page-bg/medium'
                },{
                    name: 'large',
                    width: 1024,
                    quality: 80,
                    suffix:'jpg',
                    dest: 'assets/images/main-page-bg/large'
                },{
                    name: 'retina',
                    width:1024,
                    quality: 100,
                    suffix:'jpg',
                    dest: 'assets/images/main-page-bg/retina'
                }],
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    src: '*.jpg',
                    //dest: 'assets/images/new/'
                }]
            }
        },
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... do I need to first put them all in the same folder, then somehow move them into their proper files

There are a couple of ways you can configure your `responsive_images` task to direct the resultant files to different destinations...

---

## Option 1

Using the [custom-dest](https://github.com/andismith/grunt-responsive-images#custom-destination) property you could configure your `responsive_images` task as follows:

#### Gruntfile.js

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({

        responsive_images: {
            allImages: {
                options: {
                    sizes: [{
                        name: 'small',
                        width: 320,
                        quality: 80
                    }, {
                        name: 'medium',
                        width: 640,
                        quality: 80
                    }, {
                        name: 'large',
                        width: 1024,
                        quality: 80
                    }, {
                        name: 'retina',
                        width: 2048,
                        quality: 80
                    }]
                },
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: './images',
                    src: '**/*.{jpg,png}',
                    custom_dest: 'assets/images/main-page-bg/{%= name %}/'
                }]
            }
        }

    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-responsive-images')

    grunt.registerTask('respImages', [
        'responsive_images:allImages'
    ]);

};
```

---

## Option 2

[grunt-responsive-images](https://github.com/andismith/grunt-responsive-images) can also be configured to utilize *multiple-targets*.

For further documentation on *multiple-targets* refer to [multi-tasks](http://gruntjs.com/creating-tasks#multi-tasks) and [Task Configuration and Targets](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#task-configuration-and-targets) in the `grunt` documentation.

***Note:*** This option is clearly more verbose than option one, however, it may offer finer control of your configuration options etc.

#### Gruntfile.js

For your scenario you can configure a separate target to include a `dest` path for each output destination folder you require. For example:

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({

        responsive_images: {
            small: { //<-- This is the Target for 'small' images
                options: {
                    sizes: [{
                        name: 'small',
                        width: 320,
                        quality: 80
                    }]
                },
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: './images',
                    src: '**/*.{jpg,png}',
                    dest: 'assets/images/main-page-bg/small'
                }]
            },
            medium: { //<-- This is the Target for 'medium' images
                options: {
                    sizes: [{
                        name: 'medium',
                        width: 640,
                        quality: 80
                    }]
                },
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: './images',
                    src: '**/*.{jpg,png}',
                    dest: 'assets/images/main-page-bg/medium'
                }]
            },
            large: { //<-- This is the Target for 'large' images
                options: {
                    sizes: [{
                        name: 'large',
                        width: 1024,
                        quality: 80
                    }]
                },
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: './images',
                    src: '**/*.{jpg,png}',
                    dest: 'assets/images/main-page-bg/large'
                }]
            },
            retina: { //<-- This is the Target for 'retina' images
                options: {
                    sizes: [{
                        name: 'retina',
                        width: 2048,
                        quality: 80
                    }]
                },
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: './images',
                    src: '**/*.{jpg,png}',
                    dest: 'assets/images/main-page-bg/retina'
                }]
            }
        }

    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-responsive-images')

    grunt.registerTask('respImages', [
        'responsive_images:small', // <-- Targets in a task are called using a colon separator. 
        'responsive_images:medium',
        'responsive_images:large',
        'responsive_images:retina'
    ]);

};
```

---

## Running `responsive_images`

The gists for option 1 and 2 can both be run via the CLI by typing the following command:

`$ grunt respImages`

This will output multiple image files, (to different destination folders), according to the `options` defined in each target.

---

## Comment

1. Currently, both options shown above assume that all source images are stored in a folder named *images* at the top level of your projects directory. This ***may*** need to be reconfigured in the `files` object , (for each *Target*), according to your directory setup.
2. I suggest trying either option demonstrated above, modify accordingly, and pick the one that best suits your requirements.